# pandas dataframe row manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm sure that I'm missing something simple, but I haven't be able to figure this one out.
I have a DataFrame in Pandas with multiple rows that have the same keys, but different information. I want to place these rows onto the same row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K0', 'K1', 'K2'],
                  'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                  'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})
```

This will give me a dataframe with 4 rows and 3 columns. But there is a duplicate value 'KO' in 'key'

Is there any way to turn this into a dataframe with 3 rows, and 5 columns like shown below?

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2'],
                  'A': ['A0', 'A2', 'A3'],
                  'B': ['B0', 'B2', 'B3'],
                  'A_1': ['A1', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
                  'B_1': ['B1', 'NaN', 'NaN']})
```

Comment: What if K0 repeats 3 times? How big will the dataframe be then?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have a dataframe with some rows that have K0 duplicated over 100 times. I still need the data all on a single row.

Comment: Yes but what will the dimension be if it is repeated those many times? Still 3 x 5?

Comment: Okay, that was what I wanted to know. This isn't easy.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Hopefully the dimensions will grow as needed with the amount of times the 'key' is repeated, removing rows from the dataframe, and added them to the end of the row with a matching key. The only way I can think of doing this is making each row its own dataframe and using the merge and concat functions in a for loop to build a new dataframe. But there must be an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform `groupby` on `cumcount`, then concatenate individual groups together.

```
gps = []
for i, g in df.groupby(df.groupby('key').cumcount()):
    gps.append(g.drop('key', 1).add_suffix(i + 1).reset_index(drop=1))

r = pd.concat(gps, 1).sort_index(axis=1)
r['key'] = df.key.unique()

r
   A1   A2  B1   B2 key
0  A0   A1  B0   B1  K0
1  A2  NaN  B2  NaN  K1
2  A3  NaN  B3  NaN  K2
```

You can shorten this somewhat using a list comprehension -

```
r = pd.concat(
         [g.drop('key', 1).add_suffix(i + 1).reset_index(drop=1) 
                    for i, g in df.groupby(df.groupby('key').cumcount())], 
         axis=1)\
      .sort_index(axis=1)

r['key'] = df.key.unique()
r
   A1   A2  B1   B2 key
0  A0   A1  B0   B1  K0
1  A2  NaN  B2  NaN  K1
2  A3  NaN  B3  NaN  K2
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `set_index`, `groupby`, `cumcount`, and `unstack`, then flatten multiindex with `map` and `format`:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['key', df.groupby('key').cumcount()]).unstack()
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
df_out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  key A_0   A_1 B_0   B_1
0  K0  A0    A1  B0    B1
1  K1  A2  None  B2  None
2  K2  A3  None  B3  None
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this alter the layout. just put `key` as an index to access fields :

```
df2 = df.set_index([df.key,df.index])
```

Then

```
In [248]: df2.loc['K1']
Out[248]: 
    A   B key
2  A2  B2  K1

In [249]: df2.loc['K0']
Out[249]: 
    A   B key
0  A0  B0  K0
1  A1  B1  K0
```

and iter on rows.